# How to generate javadoc for multi flavor android project in Azure DevOps pipelines?

Tags: android, gradle, azure-pipelines, build.gradle, javadoc

Android App Generate JavaDocs with Gradle 7.4 using Azure DevOps task

Hello all,
I'm trying to implement a task in Azure DevOps to generate a JavaDoc with the task as below:

```js
  - task: Gradle@2
    displayName: Generate JavaDocs
    inputs:
      gradleWrapperFile: '$(workingDirectory)/gradlew'
      workingDirectory: '$(workingDirectory)'
      tasks: 'docs'
      javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'    
      jdkVersionOption: '1.11' 
      testRunTitle: Generate JavaDocs
```

This task needs to generate the javadocs to the android app, to make this happen, I need to make some changes in my build.gradle file inside app directory.
Can someone point me in the right direction perhaps a proper documentation link? OR some inputs on how I can achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: If you have not specified any custom task as `docs` in your build.gradle file, then no such task exists in gradle. You need to use the [gradle javadoc](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.javadoc.Javadoc.html) task to generate the javadoc.

Comment: Hello Jay, thank you for getting back to me, I tried adding it in build.gradle of app module. Unfortunately, the pipeline fails, do you happen to know if there's a detailed documentation? Thanks